# Yii2 set active user in API

Tags: yii2

In Yii 1, I had this code in an API controller to set the active user:

```
Yii::$app->user->id = $my_userid;
```

But in Yii2, this is not allow, as Yii::$app->user->id is now read-only.

What would be the equivalent command to set active user id?

Comment: Refer this: stackoverflow.com/questions/30442609/how-to-change-current-user-in-yii2

Comment: By the way, there is no `Yii::$app` in Yii1, did you mean `Yii::app()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [setIdentity()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#setIdentity%28%29-detail) method for API:

```
use Yii;

...

Yii::$app->user->setIdentity($user)
```

> `setIdentity()`: changes the user identity without touching session or
>   cookie. This is best used in stateless RESTful API implementation.

where `$user` should be valid instance of your `User` model.

If you need to change existing user, use [switchIdentity()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#switchIdentity%28%29-detail) method instead:

```
use Yii;

...

Yii::$app->user->switchIdentity($user)
```

Comment: This code is in an API controller...so how do I can the valid user instance for the user? The remote service sends user credentials via POST.

Comment: @lilbiscuit Find user using sended credentials (for example `email` and `password`) and then pass it to `setIdentity()` or `switchIdentity()` method.

Comment: Works!  `$user = User::find()->where('username = "'  . $_POST['username'] . '"')->one();`

Comment: @lilbiscuit You can just use `User::findOne(['username' => $username])`. Don't forget to check `$_POST` value for existence and user for existence too. And check if provided password is correct using dedicated method.